# Select... From... Where with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to build a custom query from `Ajax` to `PHP/MySQL` considering the following.

**Javascript code:**

```
var i=2;
fetchFromDBPHP("name", "tblperson", "id="+i);    

function fetchFromDBPHP(column, table, condition) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "./php/fetchFromDB.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { column: column, table: table, condition: condition },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Fetched data from PHP:" + data);
        },
        error:function(request, status, error) {
            console.log("Reading PHP database went wrong. Error " + request.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
    $column = $_POST['column'];
    $table = $_POST['table'];
    $condition = $_POST['condition'];

    if (isset($table)) {
        $sql = "SELECT " . intval($_POST['column']) . " FROM " . intval($_POST['table']) . " WHERE " . intval($_POST['condition']);
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "bloh", "blah");
        if (!$con) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_error($con));
        }
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $to_encode = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
            $to_encode[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($to_encode);
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
?>
```

My table may be similar as that:

**Table `tblperson`:**

```
id  name    firstname   tel
1   Dalton  Jack        555-5555
2   Smith   John        555-6666
3   Doe     John        555-7777
```

What I would like to do is to send a query similar to

```
SELECT something FROM mytable WHERE condition=that
```

with Ajax.
I have an error message, and nothing is retrieved.

Comment: why you are using `intval()`?

Comment: I tried without, but I still have my error message. I agree, it's not needed.

Comment: have you check your network tab?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "network tab"...

Comment: this is network tab in browser press F12 to open : http://infoheap.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/chrome-developer-tools-network-tab.png

Comment: I just went there, but I'm not sure what to see. I have no error here.

Comment: May be you are hitting wrong url `url: "/php/fetchFromDB.php",` or it should be `url: "../php/fetchFromDB.php",` ? check

Answer (score 0):

Remove `intVal` It makes words to  `0` : check this https://eval.in/860766

```
    $column = $_POST["column"]?:"";
    $table = $_POST["table"]?:"";
    $condition = $_POST["condition"]?:"";
    if($column && $table && $condition){
      $sql = "SELECT `$column` FROM `$table` WHERE $condition";
    }else{
      die("Something went wrong.");
    }
```

Also be sure about string type value in condition, Lets say for column `address`

```
fetchFromDBPHP("name", "tblperson", "id='"+address+"'");
```

Use quotes `'` so that it would be right query like Or Make a condition in php like this

```
$condition = explode("=",$condition);
if(!is_numeric($condition[1])){
 $condition[1] = "'".$condition[1]."'"; 
}
$condition  = implode("=",$condition);
```

Demo : https://eval.in/860838 , to make query like this

```
SELECT something FROM mytable WHERE condition='that'
```

You can use above code as first step, don't use in production, make another step to make it `parameterized` or use `pdo`.

Comment: **Danger! DO NOT USE THIS CODE!**: It is **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @Quentin : I am completely agree with you. I have updated and put a note at last to use `parameterized` or `pdo`. Or should I remove this answer ?

Comment: If the answer is "You're using a form of SQL injection defence that is designed for use specifically when the input should be a number but your input is not a number" then I'd suggest either following through and showing the right way to do the protection or voting to close a duplicate of the reference SQL injection question and making a comment about the problem being that the wrong method was selected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to "user2486", my code was wrong. The right use is:

```
fetchFromDBPHP("name", "tblperson", "id='"+address+"'");
```

But, I also agree with "Quentin", the rest of his code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.